# Fpdf Printer printing small and on the left Custom page size

Tags: php, printing, fpdf

Im using Fpdf to solve a problem in a printer that is connected to a network, With Fpdf I was hoping that every computer on the network would print in the same way and get same result, But im getting a problem. One PC the one that gots the printer Epson lx-350 is printing small and on the left every other pc is printing ok Im using a custom paper size (9.8in x 6in). I have reinstalled the drivers and nothing, plus the problem started a few days ago and only in that pc, everything looks good in setting. the only difference between the pc that host the printer and the others is that the host runs on win 7 and the others on XP so is weird that XP prints correct and 7 small.

This is the paper that im trying to print on
[Off printing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2b3us.png)

And here is the  pdf file that im generating with FPDF
https://ccromatica.com/fpdf/printable4.php

Maybe someone can print this on a 9.8in x 6  custom paper to check if its a problem with the file but I guess is not as in the preview it looks ok.

Comment: I had a similar Issue. It finally depended on the OS of the Computers and not on FPDF or the Printer.

Comment: Did you find any solution to at least make it similar because right now its printing in one quarter of the whole paper. @Bernhard. Thanks for your comment

Comment: No, unfortunately not. In the End, I adjusted the PDF-File in a way, that it fit.